# Laravel api returns 401 to front-end

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Well, here is the case:
I did build a web application in laravel, used Passport package to build APIs so it can be consumable by another apps. Which works perfectly when Authenticating by Bearer User Token.
Now as I decided to consume the same API by new VueJS Front-End, as mentioned [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript), but it returns 401 code response!

I double checked all the steps, middlewares required to be added to kernel, guards in auth.php and I assured the request is going with all required headers (X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-XSRF-TOKEN,X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest).

I even compared it with another application I've done (which is working perfectly) and it was the same request.

Do anyone has a clue where else to check?

Comment: Check the logs if there are any.

Comment: I'm not sure that is relevant as no error is rising but I found this:
local.ERROR: The resource owner or authorization server denied the request. {"exception":"[object] (League\\OAuth2\\Server\\Exception\\OAuthServerException(code: 9): The resource owner or authorization server denied the request. at /home/vagrant/code/ref/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Exception/OAuthServerException.php:215)

Comment: thank you for your time, it was my fault, when I was setting up my application I didn't run 'composer require laravel/passport' I did run it then run 'artisan passport:install' and all worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was my fault, when I was setting up my application I didn't run 'composer require laravel/passport' I did run it then run 'artisan passport:install' and all worked.